# Syndrome computation of BCH code

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

I'm just trying to understand one basic property of BCH code. It was mentioned in many articles that, for binary BCH code, syndrome computation has such property: $$S_{2i+1} = (y(\alpha^{i+1}))^2=S_i^2$$, where $y(x)$ is the received codeword. However, I wonder if all the polynomial evaluation over the finite field elements under the same cyclotomic cosets can be done in a similar way. For example, for $GF(2^3)$, $\{\alpha^3,\alpha^5,\alpha^6\}$ is the coset, where $\alpha^6 = \alpha^{3*2} \ \text{and} \ \alpha^5 = \alpha^{3*2^2 mod \ 7}$. As shown above, $S_5 = S_2^2$. However, isn't that $S_4 = S_2^{2^2}$? The prove is shown as follows $$S_2^{2^2} = (y(\alpha^3))^{2^2} \\ = y(\alpha^{12 \ mod \ 7}) \\ = y(\alpha^{5}) \\ =S_4$$. Can someone helps me verify if this is true? Note: For binary BCH code, $(y(\alpha^3))^{2^2} = y(\alpha^{12})$ is valid. For the reference, this property is mentioned in this article: "Generalized Integrated Interleaved Codes" by Yingquan Wu.

Edited version:
Since this question is not clear, I would like to simplify it into one short question. For $GF(2^8)$, is $$y(α^{49})=(y(α^{19}))^{2^4}$$ right or wrong? If it is wrong, can someone prove it to me?

So the conclusion by @rcgldr:
The above equality is correct. And, $S_{48}=S_{18}^{2^4}$

Comment: Can you _provide a reference_ to at least one article which states that $S_{2i+1}$, which typically means the value of $y$ evaluated at $\alpha^{2i+1}$ and not the square of the value of $y$ at $\alpha^{i+1}$ , equals $S_i^2$??  As a general rule, $S_{2i} = y(\alpha^{2i}) = y(\alpha^i)^2 =  S_i^2$

Comment: The reference is attached in the question. Actually, both are the same thing. Just that $S_i = y(\alpha^{i+1})$ in this situation.

Comment: The point of my question is that this property does not restrict to the case of taking the square. The syndromes corresponding to the finite field elements in the same cyclotomic coset can be computed in the same manner

Comment: @DilipSarwate - This works because in larger fields, $S_2^4 = S_{11}$, and in GF(2^3), $S_{11} = S_{11\%7} = S_4$.

Answer (score 1):

This question uses nonstandard notation.

From the equation fragment $(y(\alpha^{i+1}))^2=S_i^2$ used by the OP, it seems that in the OP's world, the following definition is believed to apply:

$$S_i \stackrel{\Delta}{=} y(\alpha^{i+1}) \tag{1}$$
in contrast to the more usual $S_i = y(\alpha^i)$.  Now, noting that $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$, we have that if $f(x)$ denotes a polynomial with coefficients in $GF(2)$, then
$$[f(x)]^2 = \left(\sum_k f_k x^k\right)^2 = \sum_k (f_k)^2 x^{2k}
= \sum_k f_k x^{2k} = f(x^2)$$
so that
$$(y(\alpha^{i+1}))^2 = y(\alpha^{2i+2}) \tag{2}$$
to which we apply the OP's convention $(1)$, viz. that the subscript on $S$ is $1$ less than the superscript on $\alpha$, to arrive at the result that
$$S_{2i+1} = y(\alpha^{2i+2}) = [y(\alpha^{i+1})]^2 = S_i^2$$
as claimed by the OP.
The OP then asks with respect to $GF(2^3)$ where $$\left\{\alpha^3, (\alpha^3)^2, (\alpha^3)^{2^2}\right\} = \left\{\alpha^3, \alpha^6, \alpha^{12}\right\} = \left\{\alpha^3, \alpha^6, \alpha^{5}\right\}$$
that while in his world,
$$S_2 = y(\alpha^3) \implies S_2^2 = (y(\alpha^3))^2 = y(\alpha^6) = y(\alpha^{5+1}) = S_5 ~\text{vide}~ (1),$$ he is not absolutely sure whether
$S_2^4$ equals $S_4$ or not.  Well,
$$S_2^4 = y(\alpha^{12}) = y(\alpha^{7+5}) = y(\alpha^5) = y(\alpha^{4+1}= S_4 ~\text{vide}~ (1)$$
sure enough.

---

And yes, the OP's claim that in $GF(2^8)$, $\alpha^{49} = (\alpha^{19})^{2^4}$ is perfectly correct. Those used to working with finite fields would simply use the law of exponents to write
$$19 \times 16 = 304 = 255+49$$ to verify the claim.

Comment: Using the questions naming convention, in a larger field, $S_2^4 = S_{11}$, but in GF(2^3), $S_{11}$ maps to  $S_4$. Likewise in a larger field, $(\alpha^{19})^4 = \alpha^{304}$, but in GF(2^8), $\alpha^{304}$ maps to $(\alpha^{49})$

Answer (score 0):

The question uses non-standard naming convention for the syndromes:
$$S_i = y(\alpha^{i+1})$$

Using the questions naming convention, the odd syndromes $S_1, S_3, S_5, ... $ are powers of other syndromes, therefore redundant and optionally skipped when using Berlekamp Massey decoder:
$$S_1 = (y(\alpha^1))^2 = S_0^2$$
$$S_3 = (y(\alpha^2))^2 = S_1^2 = S_0^4$$
$$S_5 = (y(\alpha^3))^2 = S_2^2$$
$$S_7 = (y(\alpha^4))^2 = S_3^2 = S_0^8$$
$$S_9 = (y(\alpha^5))^2 = S_4^2$$
$$S_{11} = (y(\alpha^6))^2 = S_5^2 = S_2^4$$

> In GF(2^3), does $S_4 = S_2^4$ ?

Yes. In a larger field, $S_2^4 = S_{11}$. In GF(2^3), $S_{11} = S_{11\%7} = S_4$.

> In GF(2^8), does $S_{48} = S_{18}^{16}$?

Yes. In a larger field, $S_{18}^{16}$ = $S_{303}$. In GF(2^8), $S_{303} = S_{303\%255} = S_{48}$.

---

Using standard naming convention for syndromes common to BCH code and Reed Solomon code:

$$S_i = y(\alpha^i)$$
$$S_{2i} = S_i^2$$

If using Berlekamp Massey decoder, then even syndromes (S<sub>2</sub>, S<sub>4</sub>, S<sub>6</sub>, ...) are redundant and can be skipped (see next section), while odd syndromes (S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>3</sub>, S<sub>5</sub>, ...) are required in order to decode.

For smaller fields of $GF(2^n)$, an even syndrome of higher order $a$ greater than $2^{n-1}$ and less than $2^{2n-2}$ will map to an odd syndrome of lower order $b$: $S_a = S_{a\%(2^{n-1})} = S_b$ This allows $S_b$ to be calculated by using the formula $S_b = S_a = S_{a/2}^2 = S_{a/4}^4 = $ ... .

Note - unlike BCH code, for Reed Solomon code, all syndromes are required.

---

To explain why the formula works for even syndromes but not odd, in GF(2^n):
$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$$
$$(a+b)^3 = a^3 + a^2 b + a b^2 + b^3$$
$$(a+b)^4 = a^4 + b^4$$
$$(a+b)^5 = a^5 + a^4 b + a b^4 + b^5$$
$$...$$
$$(a+b+c\ +...)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ... $$

Consider a 2 error case in GF(2^8) with reducing polynomial hex 11d, 6 syndromes, with errors at x^4 and x^8. Using hex:
$$S_1 = (2^1)^4 + (2^1)^8 = 0d $$
$$S_2 = (2^2)^4 + (2^2)^8 = 51 $$
$$S_3 = (2^3)^4 + (2^3)^8 = 42 $$
$$S_4 = (2^4)^4 + (2^4)^8 = d1 $$
$$S_5 = (2^5)^4 + (2^5)^8 = de $$
$$S_6 = (2^6)^4 + (2^6)^8 = c9 $$
For the even syndromes:
$$S_1^2 = ((2^1)^4 + (2^1)^8)^2 = ((2^1)^4)^2 + ((2^1)^8)^2 = (2^2)^4 + (2^2)^8 = S_2$$
$$S_2^2 = ((2^2)^4 + (2^2)^8)^2 = ((2^2)^4)^2 + ((2^2)^8)^2 = (2^4)^4 + (2^4)^8 = S_4$$
$$S_3^2 = ((2^3)^4 + (2^3)^8)^2 = ((2^3)^4)^2 + ((2^3)^8)^2 = (2^6)^4 + (2^6)^8 = S_6$$
But this strategy doesn't work for the odd syndromes.

Comment: Ok. But, for GF(2^8), why $y(\alpha^{49})$ cannot computed from $y(\alpha^{19})$. As $\alpha^{49} = \alpha^{19*2^4 \ mod \ 255}$. This two finite field elements belong to the same cyclotomic coset.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  I know that when taking an odd power of a polynomial, the power can not be directly applied to the coefficient of the polynomial as shown in the second and fourth equation. However, for the way of constructing the cyclotomic coset, some finite field element with odd power can be derived by each other.

Comment: For example, consider GF(2^8). $\{\alpha^{19},\alpha^{19*2},\alpha^{19*2^2},\cdots,\alpha^{19*2^7}\}$ is the one of the coset. Taking the modulo of $2^8-1 = 255$, the coset is constructed as $\{\alpha^{19},\alpha^{38},\alpha^{49},\alpha^{76},\alpha^{98},\alpha^{137},\alpha^{152},\alpha^{196}\}$.

Comment: You can see that $(\alpha^{19})^{2^4}=\alpha^{19*2^4 \ \text{mod} \ 255}=\alpha^{49}$. Therefore, why $y(\alpha^{49}) = (y(\alpha^{19}))^{2^4}$ is wrong, which I really don't get it.

Comment: To explain how the second equation is derived, since $y(x)$ is a binary polynomial and we are taking an exponent of power of 2, $(y(\alpha^{19}))^{2^4}=y(\alpha^{19*2^4 \ \text{mod} \ 255}) = y(\alpha^{49})$.

Comment: I do not intend to use $\alpha^{19}$ as a primitive element. You did not specifically answer the question I ask above. Why $y(α^{49})=(y(α^{19}))^{2^4}$ is wrong.

Comment: The modification you made above does not prove whether if this equality is right or wrong.

Comment: $\alpha$ is defined as a primitive element here.

Comment: I saw your revised answer. The point of my question is not focusing on the odd syndromes of BCH codes. Some of the odd syndromes can be computed in a much simpler method as I mentioned above. Specifically for the equality that I've shown above, can you prove if it is right or wrong? Or there is no point for me to keep my discussion with you further.

Comment: Your statement regarding $S_4 = S_2^4$ is wrong. I'm really don't know why taking the module will change the result. For example, $y(x)=1+x+x^3$. $y(\alpha^5) = 1+\alpha^5 + \alpha^{15 \ \text{mod} \ 7 = 1}$. $(y(\alpha^3))^{2^2} = 1+(\alpha^3)^{2^2} + (\alpha^9)^{2^2} = 1+ \alpha^5 +\alpha^{9*4 \text{mod} \ 7 = 1}$.

Comment: You are throwing those statements to me without actually prove it whether if it is right or wrong.

Comment: Which part of the equation shows that it involves higher-order syndromes that exceed the range for GF(2^n)? We are computing the same syndromes, just that the actual computation of this method involves modulo, which is the backbone of FINITE FIELD.

Comment: You seem to say that $S_2^4 = S_{11}$ which is not considered in the syndrome computation of GF(2^3)

Comment: If this statement is true, the whole idea of cyclotomic coset is collapsed.

Comment: This is not true. The actual computation of $S_2^4$ involves modulo. It is not equal to $S_{11}$.

Comment: Please answer my questions. 1) is $(y(α^3))^{2^2} = y(\alpha^5)$? 2) If this is equal, why $S^4_2 \neq S_4$? This has nothing to do with $S_{11}$ and the range of $GF(2^3)$.

Comment: $S_2^4 = S_4$ won't affect the actual implementation of BKM algorithm. $S_{2i+1}=S_i^2$ is the backbone of the BKM algorithm of BCH code as it shows the odd iteration of BKM can be skipped. The point of saying $S_2^4 = S_4$ is just simplifying the syndrome computations. It does not affect the discrepancies result of the even iterations as not all even syndromes can be computed in the same way. Only those in the same CYCLOTOMIC COSET have this property. So can you please answer my questions above? This will take no end if you keep avoiding to answer my questions specifically.

Comment: Thats why I mention 100 of times. $S_2^4=S_4$ does not follow the same property, $S_{2i+1}=S_i^2$. But it actually can be computed in that way. I'm really don't understand why you keep saying the equality, $S_2^4=S_4$, is not true. This won't affect the BKM results as not every even syndromes computed in this way, where only those in the same CYCLOTOMIC COSET.

Comment: Can you prove it to me if the value of $S^4_2$ is not equal to $S_4$.

Comment: More questions are asked in the chat.@rcgldr